# Select input is not working in Shiny application

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am trying to build an application in R with Shiny doing the following steps:

1. Read the CSV data
2. Histogram for every variable
3. Further analysis

I am able to read CSV data but unable to display the colnames of the data in selectinput.

Code is running but the display of variable names is not working.

My code is:

```
library(shiny)
ui<-navbarPage("Model Developement by Subhasish",
           tabPanel("Data Import",sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel( fileInput("file","Upload your CSV",multiple = FALSE),
                                                              tags$hr(),
                                                              h5(helpText("Select the read.table parameters below")),
                                                              checkboxInput(inputId = 'header', label = 'Header', value = FALSE),
                                                              checkboxInput(inputId = "stringAsFactors", "stringAsFactors", FALSE),
                                                              radioButtons(inputId = 'sep', label = 'Separator', choices = c(Comma=',',Semicolon=';',Tab='\t', Space=''), selected = ',')
           ),
           mainPanel(uiOutput("tb1"))
           ) ),
           tabPanel("Histogram",sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(
             selectInput("headers","Select variable to view Histogram",choices =as.list(names(data)),multiple = FALSE)),mainPanel("mainpanel"))),
           tabPanel("More")
)
server<-function(input,output) { data <- reactive({
  file1 <- input$file
  if(is.null(file1)){return()} 
  read.table(file=file1$datapath, sep=input$sep, header = input$header, stringsAsFactors = input$stringAsFactors)
  
})  
output$table <- renderTable({
  if(is.null(data())){return ()}
  data()
})
output$tb1 <- renderUI({
  tableOutput("table")
})
}
shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

Comment: Basically the issue is that you are trying to access the `data` file's column names from the `ui` but you can't do that unless you pass the names over from the `server`. You have 2 options: 1) Make the `selectInput` in the ui and then use `updateSeletctInput` in the server, 2) make the `selectInput` on the server and then pass it using `renderUI` and `uiOutput`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I added an example how you may proceed. I tested it with my dummy `.csv` file, so it should work. I also added some test cases for the histogram so you don't get the errors printed.

I added the following changes

1. I used `renderUI` to create the `selectInput` called *headers*
2. The table output is best to be rendered directly using the `tableOutput("table")`
3. I added the histogram plot as you wanted one

Example:

```
library(shiny)
ui<-navbarPage("Model Developement by Subhasish",
               tabPanel("Data Import",sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel( fileInput("file","Upload your CSV",multiple = FALSE),
                                                                  tags$hr(),
                                                                  h5(helpText("Select the read.table parameters below")),
                                                                  checkboxInput(inputId = 'header', label = 'Header', value = FALSE),
                                                                  checkboxInput(inputId = "stringAsFactors", "stringAsFactors", FALSE),
                                                                  radioButtons(inputId = 'sep', label = 'Separator', choices = c(Comma=',',Semicolon=';',Tab='\t', Space=''), selected = ',')
               ),
               mainPanel(tableOutput("table")))),
               tabPanel("Histogram",sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(
                 uiOutput("ui1")),
                 mainPanel(plotOutput("myhist")))),
               tabPanel("More")
)
server<-function(input,output) { 

  data <- reactive({
    file1 <- input$file
    if(is.null(file1)){return()} 
    read.table(file=file1$datapath, sep=input$sep, header = input$header, stringsAsFactors = input$stringAsFactors)
  }) 

  output$table <- renderTable({
    if(is.null(data())){return ()}
    data()
  })
  output$ui1 <- renderUI({
    selectInput("headers","Select variable to view Histogram",choices =as.list(names(data())),multiple = FALSE)
  })

  output$myhist <- renderPlot({
    histdata <- suppressWarnings(as.numeric((data()[,names(data()) %in% input$headers])))
    histdata <- histdata[!is.na(histdata)]
    if(length(histdata) == 0){
      return()
    }
    hist(histdata,breaks=10)
    box();grid() 
  })
}
shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Pork Chop for the answer. I will use you way in my next work. As I am new in shiny. can you guide me why you have used box(),grid();??

Comment: `box(),grid();` is just added a box and a grid to the plot, that is all, simply to make it pretty